# How to obtain arguments passed to setup.py from pip with '--install-option'?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I am using pip 1.4.1, attempting to install a package from a local path, for example:

```
pip install /path/to/my/local/package
```

This does what I want, which is more or less the equivalent of running `python /path/to/my/local/package/setup.py install`, but I would like to pass some additional options/arguments to my package's setup.py install.

I understand [from the pip documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#install-install-option) that this is possible with the `--install-option` option, for example:

```
pip install --install-option="--some-option" /path/to/my/local/package
```

[This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-virtualenv/a6yFIT9KDwI) from the python-virtualenv Google Group suggests this is possible.

What I do not understand is how to obtain the passed-in "--some-option" from within setup.py. I tried looking at `sys.argv`, but no matter what I put for "--install-option=", `sys.argv` is always this:

```
['-c', 'egg_info', '--egg-base', 'pip-egg-info']
```

How can I get the values of things passed in as "--install-option" from pip install?

Comment: Related: [distutils: How to pass a user defined parameter to setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677577/distutils-how-to-pass-a-user-defined-parameter-to-setup-py)

Answer (score 25):

You need to extend the install command with a custom command of your own. In the `run` method you can expose the value of the option to `setup.py` (in my example I use a global variable).

```
from setuptools.command.install import install


class InstallCommand(install):
    user_options = install.user_options + [
        ('someopt', None, None), # a 'flag' option
        #('someval=', None, None) # an option that takes a value
    ]

    def initialize_options(self):
        install.initialize_options(self)
        self.someopt = None
        #self.someval = None

    def finalize_options(self):
        #print("value of someopt is", self.someopt)
        install.finalize_options(self)

    def run(self):
        global someopt
        someopt = self.someopt # will be 1 or None
        install.run(self)
```

Register the custom install command with the `setup` function.

```
setup(
    cmdclass={
        'install': InstallCommand,
    },
    :
```

It seems that the order of your arguments is off

`pip install /path/to/my/local/package --install-option="--someopt"`

Comment: By the way, once you subclass the install command you should be able to see those on `sys.argv`.

Comment: Just to clarify, within setup(...) how you would access the variable you've passed in using the cmdclass technique?

Comment: The cmdclass sets up having an option (at all). Without it pip will complain and not execute the action. It will pass it along to setup.py, and in there you can inspect your sys.argv for the value of the option.

Comment: By the way, using underscores in the `user_options` seems forbidden: `distutils.errors.DistutilsGetoptError: invalid long option name 'some_option' (must be letters, numbers, hyphens only`

Right, I'm trying to use the commented out 'some_val' version of this code and end up with `error: option --someval not recognised`. This is despite the fact that `python setup.py install -h` shows that the new flag being recognised.

Comment: Odd, this wasn't a problem with the version of setuptools I worked with. Ugh, the documentation is horrendous. Anyway, thanks for the tip Mani. I fixed the example.

Comment: this simply does not work, pip ingests the options and sends them to /dev/null :(

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/blob/master/setup.py#L226-L229

Comment: `--install-option` was deprecated in [pip 22.3](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v22-3) and removed in [pip 23.1](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v23-1).

Answer (score 11):

For consistency, you can add an option to both `setup.py install` and `setup.py develop` (aka `pip install -e`): (building off Ronen Botzer's answer)

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
from setuptools.command.develop import develop


class CommandMixin(object):
    user_options = [
        ('someopt', None, 'a flag option'),
        ('someval=', None, 'an option that takes a value')
    ]

    def initialize_options(self):
        super().initialize_options()
        # Initialize options
        self.someopt = None
        self.someval = 0

    def finalize_options(self):
        # Validate options
        if self.someval < 0:
            raise ValueError("Illegal someval!")
        super().finalize_options()

    def run(self):
        # Use options
        global someopt
        someopt = self.someopt # will be 1 or None

        super().run()

class InstallCommand(CommandMixin, install):
    user_options = getattr(install, 'user_options', []) + CommandMixin.user_options

class DevelopCommand(CommandMixin, develop):
    user_options = getattr(develop, 'user_options', []) + CommandMixin.user_options

setup(
    ...,
    cmdclass={
        'install': InstallCommand,
        'develop': DevelopCommand,
    }
```

Then you can pass options to pip like:

```
pip install --install-option="--someval=1" --install-option="--someopt" .
```

Or in develop mode:

```
pip install -e --install-option="--someval=1" .
```

Comment: I want to send include_dirs and library_dirs to build my module, previously I'd populate the include_dirs and library_dirs in setup(), how should I be going about this now?

Comment: @Rika Don't do this via the install command. Instead look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/51522248/81658

Answer (score 7):

It works well and also [documented](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-install-option).

```
from setuptools.command.install import install

class InstallCommand(install):             
    user_options = install.user_options + [
        ('engine=', None, '<description for this custom option>'),
    ]                                      

    def initialize_options(self):          
        install.initialize_options(self)   
        self.engine = None  

    def finalize_options(self):                   
        print("value of engine is", self.engine)
        install.finalize_options(self)            

    def run(self):                                
        print(self.engine)                       
        install.run(self)                         

setup(
...
cmdclass={'install': InstallCommand}
...
)
```

One of common mistakes is to pass `setup` options to pip like you pass it to `setup` directly. **Use options from pip like that:**

```
pip install . --install-option="--engine=rabbitmq"
```

#### But this way is a wrong way:

```
pip install . --install-option="--engine rabbitmq"
```

Absence of equal sign causes well known error:

> error: option --engines rabbitmq not recognized

Comment: The link was removed

Comment: `--install-option` is now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem installing pyside.

I needed to specify the `--qmake` option.

This is the form you need:

```
pip install --install-option="--qmake=/usr/lib64/qt4/bin/qmake" PySide
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I had set this aside as I found other ways around the problem a while ago, but I will give that a try and see. As I recall, I don't think it worked; there is some difference between installing a local package versus one from PyPI but I may be mistaken.

Comment: This option `--qmake` is related to project `PySide`. To add a custom option you need to register derived class of `setuptools.command.install` (and/or `.develop`) to manage it (as written in the answers above).

Answer (score -1):

On top of this [great anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33200591/5335565).
One more thing to notice is that [--install-options](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-install-option) doesn't [work with wheel](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#per-requirement-overrides)

> Since version 7.0 pip supports controlling the command line options given to setup.py via requirements files. This disables the use of wheels (cached or otherwise) for that package, as setup.py does not exist for wheels.

However, when you build the wheel with `setup.py`, you can use

```sh
python setup.py bdist_wheel install -your-options
```

To customize the install phase and this will affect the `.dist-info` of the wheel package.