# Get extra argument passed on the installation

Tags: python

Related to this question:
[Specify extras_require with pip install -e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239152/specify-extras-require-with-pip-install-e)

There is some way to get the argument passed by the user as extra programmatically?

i.e. when some user execute:

```
pip install pkg[extra]
```

I would like to capture that **extra** argument that the user has put and do something in `setup.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extra_require` is not really supposed to be used this way, it only specifies a dependency.

If you want to provide a custom option, you should write something like this

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install

class InstallCommand(install):
    user_options = install.user_options + [
        ('someopt', None, None),    # a 'flag' option
        ('someval=', None, None)    # an option that takes a value
    ]

    def initialize_options(self):
        install.initialize_options(self)
        self.someopt = None
        self.someval = None

    def finalize_options(self):
        super(InstallCommand, self).finalize_options()
        assert self.someopt
        assert self.someval == 'asdf'

setup(
    name="pkg",

    cmdclass={
        'install': InstallCommand,
    },
)
```

which can then be used as

```
./setup.py install --someopt --someval=asdf
```

or with pip

```
pip install pkg --install-option='--someopt' --install-option='--someval=asdf'
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20248942/1028589), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33200591/1028589)