# Passing command line arguments to pip install

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I'm currently working on a Python project that is importing a Fortran module. The `setup.py` looks similar to that

```
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension
from numpy.distutils.core import setup

ext = Extension(
    name = "fortran_module",
    sources = ["fortran_module.f90"],
    extra_f90_compile_args = ["-some -compile -arguments"]
)

setup(
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    ext_modules = [ext],
    ...,
    ...,
    ...
)
```

I'm currently installing it with `pip install -e .`, which works fine.
But sometimes I need to change the `extra_f90_compile_args` and I would like to do give them as command line argument during installation with `pip` rather than changing the `setup.py` file. Something like this for example:

```
pip install -e --compile_args="-O3 -fbacktrace -fbounds-check -fopenmp" .
```

Is it possible to pass command line arguments via `pip` into the `setup.py` file?

Related to that, I would also like to pass different setup options into `setup.py`. For example

```
pip install -e --setup=setup1 .
```

or

```
pip install -e --setup=setup2 .
```

And depending on whether `setup1` or `setup2` or none of them is passed, I would like to include different Fortran source files and compile them with different `extra_f90_compile_args`.

Is this possible?

---

**Edit:** Let's consider the following example: The Fortran module is parallelized with OpenMP. Now I want the user to decide, whether to compile parallel or not. Maybe the OpenMP libraries are not available and the user needs to compile the serial version.

My `setup.py` now looks as follows

```
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension
from numpy.distutils.core import setup
import os
from setuptools.command.install import install as _install

extra_f90_compile_args = ""
extra_link_args = ""

class install(_install):
    user_options = _install.user_options + [('build=', None, None)]

    def initialize_options(self):
        _install.initialize_options(self)
        self.build = None

    def finalize_options(self):
        _install.finalize_options(self)

    def run(self):
        global extra_f90_compile_args
        global extra_link_args
        if(self.build == "parallel"):
            extra_f90_compile_args += "-fopenmp"
            extra_link_args += "-lgomp"
            os.makedirs("~/test/")
        _install.run(self)

ext = Extension(
    name="test_module.fortran_module",
    sources=["test_module/fortran_module.f90"],
    extra_f90_compile_args=[extra_f90_compile_args],
    extra_link_args=[extra_link_args]
)

setup(
    name="test_module",
    packages=["test_module"],
    ext_modules=[ext],
    cmdclass={'install': install}
)
```

If I install this with

```
pip install . --install-option="--build=parallel"
```

it is executing code in the `if`-block. I created the `test/` directory just to check this. If `build` is not given or different from `parallel`, the `test/` directory is not created.

However, the code is not compiled with OpenMP. I think this is, because the `Extension` object is created before the call of `setup()`, where the arguments get evaluated. I would like to first evaluate the arguments, then create the `Extension` object depending on the arguments, and then call `setup()`.

How can I do that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33200591/7976758

Comment: I'm aware of this and several other questions. However, I cannot get it to work in my case. See edit.

Comment: In the added code there is indentation problem — methods are not properly indented. Please fix.

Comment: Fixed.
My problem is that I would like to evaluate the arguments in the `setup.py` file **before** `setup()` is called.

Comment: Aha, I see — you need to evaluate `ext` from the global vars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging through the source code, I can answer this now.

The `setup.py` file:

```
from numpy.distutils.command.install import install as _install
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension
from numpy.distutils.core import setup

extF = Extension(name="test_module.fortran_module",
                 sources=["test_module/fortran_module.f90"])
compile_args_parallel = "-fopenmp"
link_args_parallel = "-lgomp"

class install(_install):
    user_options = _install.user_options + [('build=', None, None)]

    def initialize_options(self):
        _install.initialize_options(self)
        self.build = None

    def finalize_options(self):
        _install.finalize_options(self)
        if(self.build == "parallel"):
            for ext in self.distribution.ext_modules:
                if(ext.name == "test_module.fortran_module"):
                    ext.extra_f90_compile_args = compile_args_parallel
                    ext.extra_link_args = link_args_parallel

    def run(self):
        _install.run(self)

setup(
    name="test_module",
    packages=["test_module"],
    ext_modules=[extF],
    cmdclass={"install": install}
)
```

Installing this with

```
pip install .
```

installs the serial version and

```
pip install . --install-option="--build=parallel"
```

installs the parallel version of the Fortran module.

Comment: I am also creating a package with some command line args. Can you tell me how to make it ?

Comment: `--install-option` was deprecated in [pip 22.3](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v22-3) and removed in [pip 23.1](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v23-1).

Answer (score 7):

Dealing with both `--install-option` and `--global-option` seems very messy if there's more than one option in my opinion. I would like to add [this real life solution](https://github.com/spotify/annoy/blob/57a47fc8a18dec6c5fd439143259ead36ec14eca/setup.py#L57-L63)

Take in environment variables instead, and set them at install time.

In setup.py:

```
import os
config_var = os.environ.get("MY_PARAM", None)
if config_var:
    do_something()
setup()
```

and call pip like this:
`MY_PARAM="Some_value" pip install my_module`