# Python - Accepting input parameter when installing package

Tags: python, setuptools

I've written a python module which when imported, assumes the **importing** file has a predefined folder name at some level up in the folder hierarchy. My module then proceeds to add the predefined folder to sys.path.

I want to upload this package to PyPI, but I want to somehow enable the user to input the pre-defined folder name on install.

I've looked at: [How to obtain arguments passed to setup.py from pip with '--install-option'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725137/how-to-obtain-arguments-passed-to-setup-py-from-pip-with-install-option) which seems closest to what  I"m trying to achieve, but the proposed  solution doesn't enable a default (user defined) configuration to the packaged module itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest that this is the kind of thing that should be in a config file that is read when the module loads, rather than an install-time parameter.

Comment: @match In retrospect you're right, I wanted to minimize user configuration, but this rules out the option of using this module for  several folders. I guess I"ll switch to an environment variable instead. Thanks!