# Overriding Python setuptool's default include_dirs and library_dirs?

Tags: python, setuptools

I specify in `setup.py` the following `include_dirs` and `library_dirs`:

```
/opt/x86_64-sdk-linux/usr/bin/python3 setup.py build_ext \
--include-dirs=/opt/neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/python3.5m/ \
--library-dirs=/opt/neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/ \
--rpath=/opt/neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/ \
--plat-name=linux_armv7l
```

However, the generated gcc commands (when executing `python3 setup.py build_ext`) also include the include path where `python3` is running from (I have added newlines for readability):

```
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc \
--sysroot=/opt/neon-poky-linux-gnueabi \
-I. \
-I/opt/neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/python3.5m/ \
-I/opt/x86_64-sdk-linux/usr/include/python3.5m \
-c py/constraint.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/py/constraint.o
```

The third include path was not specified explicitly, but is still used when compiling.

How would I go about ensuring only the `include-dirs` I specify are being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to override `build_ext` command because [the stdlib's `build_ext` ensures the Python header files, both platform specific and not, are always appended to the include paths](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d0cdeaab76fef8a6e5a04665df226b6659111e4e/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py#L150-L155).

Here's an example of custom `build_ext` command that cleans up the include paths after the options are finalized:

```
# setup.py

from distutils import sysconfig
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext as build_ext_orig


class build_ext(build_ext_orig):

    def finalize_options(self):
        super().finalize_options()
        py_include = sysconfig.get_python_inc()
        plat_py_include = sysconfig.get_python_inc(plat_specific=1)
        for path in (py_include, plat_py_include, ):
            for _ in range(self.include_dirs.count(path)):
                self.include_dirs.remove(path)


setup(
    ...,
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
)
```

#### Update

Same approach for library dirs: clean the list when options are finalized:

```
class build_ext(build_ext_orig):

    def finalize_options(self):
        super().finalize_options()
        ...
        libdir = sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR')
        for _ in range(self.library_dirs.count(libdir)):
            self.library_dirs.remove(libdir)
```

Comment: Any advice for modifying the library directories used for linking in the later stages of the setup? I'm running into a similar issue where it's ensuring `/usr/lib` under the `x86_64-sdk` path is being added (since that's where `python3` is located), even when that path is not being specified in the `--library-dirs` argument.

Comment: The approach for cleaning up the library dirs is the same; I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Does this also work with distutils? (no setuptools used here)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb sure, just override the `distutils.command.build_ext.build_ext` instead.