# How to setup application to personalize it?

Tags: python, parameters, pip, installation

I'm working on simple opensource project. [Github link](https://github.com/ethru/WorkTimeSaver). Application is written with `tkinter`. It is kind of calculator. I want to allow user to configure it during installation (but only then, no separate menu for changing settings). At the moment default values are saved in class. I would like to add possibility to use: `pip3 install . --install-option="--customize={'my_value1': 1, 'my_value2': 2}"`. I know that I can add them one by one, but it will be many of them that's why I decided to use dictionary. Below I'm adding my code where I try to save those settings to `json` file and use it later with application:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
from json import dumps, loads, JSONDecodeError


class Handler:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.config = 'WorkTimeSaver/data.json'
        self.data = self.convert(data)
        if self.data:
            self.save()
        else:
            print('Wrong format of data, default values will be used.')

    def convert(self, settings):
        try:
            data = loads(settings)
            if isinstance(data, dict):
                return data
        except JSONDecodeError:
            return False

    def save(self):
        with open(self.config, 'w') as config:
            config.write(dumps(self.data))


class InstallCommand(install):
    user_options = install.user_options + [
        ('customize=', None, 'pass dictionary with values used to calculate salary'),
    ]

    def initialize_options(self):
        install.initialize_options(self)
        self.customize = None

    def finalize_options(self):
        install.finalize_options(self)

    def run(self):
        Handler(self.customize)
        install.run(self)


setup(
    name='WorkTimeSaver',
    packages=['WorkTimeSaver'],
    entry_points={'console_scripts': 'WorkTimeSaver=WorkTimeSaver.__main__:main'},
    cmdclass={'install': InstallCommand}
)
```

Problem with code above is that it is not creating any `json` file. Not in installation directory and not even in package directory. It is first time when I try to develop my own package. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725137/how-to-obtain-arguments-passed-to-setup-py-from-pip-with-install-option) helped me to write code up. I don't know how to correct it. Could you tell me please how can I fix it? Is there more elegant way to achieve it (not using `json` file for example)?

Comment: Can you just have a flat file that holds configs with a boolean that is set to zero. Then on first run of program you check that boolean then ask the user to update some configs in a pop up window and after that the boolean is set to 1 so from now on it does not ask to update.

Comment: ***"allow user to configure it during installation (but only then"***: Such a approach is kind of hassle. How will a user edit a mistyped data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe *pip* is not designed to allow configuration at *install-time*. It is somewhat possible (under specific conditions) to do such a thing via custom *setuptools* commands like shown in the question for example, but there are many scenarios in which this will not work (in short: built distributions such as wheel do not contain the `setup.py` file, so it can't run at *install-time*) and many reasons why we don't want something like this to work.

A common recommendation (best practice?) is to run such customization during the first run of the application instead.