# add flags to pip install -e in setup.py

Tags: python, parsing, pip, setuptools

I have a small package and I want to customize my `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import sys

if '--bla' in sys.argv:
    sys.argv.remove('--bla')
    print('bla!')

setup(name='my_pkg', packages=find_packages())
```

This `setup.py` allows me to run

`python setup.py bdist_wheel` and `python setup.py bdist_wheel --bla`

```
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel
running bdist_wheel
...


$ python setup.py bdist_wheel --bla
bla!
running bdist_wheel
...
```

however, running `pip install -e --bla` breaks:

```
$ pip install -e . --bla

Usage:   
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --bla
```

Can I make `pip` respect the `setup.py` argument parser? Is there a better place to add the parser so I would be able to both create wheels and install in editable mode?

Comment: You probably want this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53833930/9203110

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain arguments passed to setup.py from pip with '--install-option'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725137/how-to-obtain-arguments-passed-to-setup-py-from-pip-with-install-option)

Comment: @user202729 not trying to compare. I want both options to work

Comment: @match this seems like a parser-per-command where my code should have handled all sub-commands...

Comment: @mat Not really a duplicate, but reading the linked question does solve this question (passing ` --install-option=--bla` to pip). https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258804/duplicate-question-but-only-when-you-know-the-answer seems to suggest closing

Comment: Besides the method linked there is the "proper" way to parse these arguments.